# Failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: Program failed to complete

Tags: anchor, anchor-spl

I am trying to initialize an escrow account and I keep getting this error.

Here's the instruction code

```
use crate::state::*;
use anchor_lang::prelude::*;
use anchor_spl::{token::{Mint, TokenAccount, Token}, associated_token::AssociatedToken};

pub fn handler(ctx: Context<InitEscrow>) -> Result<()> {
    let escrow_account = &mut ctx.accounts.escrow_account;
    escrow_account.bump = *ctx.bumps.get("escrow_account").unwrap();

    escrow_account.borrower = ctx.accounts.borrower.key();
    escrow_account.loan = ctx.accounts.loan_account.key();
    escrow_account.nft_mint = ctx.accounts.nft_mint.key();
    escrow_account.escrow_nft_vault = ctx.accounts.escrow_nft_vault.key();
    escrow_account.token_mint = ctx.accounts.token_mint.key();
    escrow_account.escrow_token_vault = ctx.accounts.escrow_token_vault.key();

    Ok(())
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct InitEscrow<'info> {
  #[account(mut)]
    pub borrower: Signer<'info>,
    #[account(
      init, 
      payer = borrower,
      space = Escrow::LEN,
      seeds = [b"escrow", borrower.key().as_ref(), loan_account.key().as_ref()],
      bump
    )]
    pub escrow_account: Account<'info, Escrow>,
    #[account(
      seeds = [b"loan", borrower.key().as_ref()],
      bump = loan_account.bump
    )]
    pub loan_account: Account<'info, Loan>,
    pub token_mint: Account<'info, Mint>,
    #[account(
      init,
      payer = borrower,
      associated_token::mint = token_mint,
      associated_token::authority = escrow_account
    )]
    pub escrow_token_vault: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,
    pub nft_mint: Account<'info, Mint>,
    #[account(
      init,
      payer = borrower,
      associated_token::mint = nft_mint,
      associated_token::authority = escrow_account
    )]
    pub escrow_nft_vault: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,
    pub token_program: Program<'info, Token>,
    pub associated_token_program: Program<'info, AssociatedToken>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}
```

Here's the test code:

```
        await program.methods
            .initEscrow()
            .accounts({
                borrower: borrowerPk,
                tokenMint: tokenMintPk,
                nftMint: nftMintPk,
                escrowAccount: escrowAccountPk,
                escrowNftVault: escrowNftVaultPk,
                escrowTokenVault: escrowTokenVaultPk,
            })
            .signers([borrower])
            .rpc({
                skipPreflight: true,
            });
    });
```

Comment: Hey. Could you try checking the logs in the .anchor directory in your root folder, or use a try..catch() block in your ts code to catch and log the error? Either of these should give you a more helpful error message.  


Looking through your code though it's possible you might not setting Escrow::LEN correctly. You can try checking that. The space allocated should be the borsh serialized size for your struct + an extra 8 bytes.

Comment: Thanks. Got the error. It was ProgramStackError. Fixed it by boxing the escrow account.

Answer (score 0):

I used a try catch block on typescript code and found the specific error. It was ProgramStackError. Fixed it by boxing the Escrow account.

Here's the updated context code:

```
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct InitEscrow<'info> {
  #[account(mut)]
    pub borrower: Signer<'info>,
    #[account(
      init, 
      payer = borrower,
      space = Escrow::LEN,
      seeds = [b"escrow", borrower.key().as_ref(), loan_account.key().as_ref()],
      bump
    )]
    pub escrow_account: Box<Account<'info, Escrow>>,
    #[account(
      seeds = [b"loan", borrower.key().as_ref()],
      bump = loan_account.bump
    )]
    pub loan_account: Account<'info, Loan>,
    pub token_mint: Account<'info, Mint>,
    #[account(
      init,
      payer = borrower,
      associated_token::mint = token_mint,
      associated_token::authority = escrow_account
    )]
    pub escrow_token_vault: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,
    pub nft_mint: Account<'info, Mint>,
    #[account(
      init,
      payer = borrower,
      associated_token::mint = nft_mint,
      associated_token::authority = escrow_account
    )]
    pub escrow_nft_vault: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,
    pub token_program: Program<'info, Token>,
    pub associated_token_program: Program<'info, AssociatedToken>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}
```